# Rails Tutorial for Devise with CanCan and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, device, cancan, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Can't run this open source project http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-bootstrap-devise-cancan.html.I'm using Ruby version1.9.3p286 and Rails 3.2.8. 
I've installed all gems successfully, but when trying to run from RubyMine output 
the following:

```
/Users/st/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/st/projects/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find diff-lcs-1.1.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in `specs'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:158:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:147:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/st/projects/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/st/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/st/projects/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan/script/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'sqlite3'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.11.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "email_spec", ">= 1.2.1", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.0", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.8.0", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.1.2", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.1.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.1.0.0"
gem "devise", ">= 2.1.2"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.8"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.3"
gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.1", :group => :development
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

little addition to @Baboon's solution, try to remove Gem.lock file and run `bundle install` again

How ever, once you are comfortable with the example, You might be interested in ["rails composer"](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/) to generate your rails skeleton

HTH

Comment: tried to remove gem.lock file and run bundle install but it couldn't help me, thank you for rails composer!

Comment: Good advice from @sameera207. Use Rails Composer to generate the app. And read this article from the author on Installing Rails: http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html

Answer (score 3):

It can't find the `diff-lcs-1.1.3` gem, try running bundle install or installing the gem manually.

EDIT: seeing your gem file, it's missing

```
gem "diff-lcs", "1.1.3"
```

Comment: Added gem "diff-lcs", "1.1.3", but now RubyMine prints Could not find multi_json-1.3.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: Add that one too, and any other it may complain about.